# Detect if a user is behind the Great Firewall of China using JS

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have researched this a lot and am yet to find a solution. I have an Angular app which calls Google Firebase Functions. My problem is China's Great Firewall blocks Google services, therefore, users behind this firewall go to my app and see the page loading forever, because the calls to Firebase Functions are never successful, and they don't seem to timeout.

What I want to do is see if the user is behind the Great Firewall of China, and display an appropriate message, instead of the page loading forever. I could detect the users location and display the message if their location is China, but I don't want to basically blacklist the whole of China, as I know some parts of China are not behind this firewall.

How can I achieve this in Angular or JS?

Comment: Why not just detect if nothing is loading and then give a message to that effect to the users? They don't need to be in China - might be their work network firewall. Or random failure. Or whatever.

Comment: @VLAZ Or might just be a bad connection, that's why I need something specific for the Great Firewall of China.

Comment: How do you differentiate it from a firewall at work?

Comment: @VLAZ my exact question. Was wondering if there was anything that would tell you. This seems like a big problem for which I thought a solution must exist.

Comment: There probably is a solution. The simplest one is test for location and connectivity and infer from there. Or test for something that's for sure blocked. However, the question is - why is any other firewall going to be different? Presumably there is little difference for the users. They cannot connect and that's it. Whether it's China or work, I don't see much of a difference. It's also mostly the same as bad connectivity.

Comment: @VLAZ you seem to make a good point. I'll give this a go. Thanks!